# Does the VCard spec dictate a maximum file size?

Tags: vcf-vcard

Is there a specified size upperbound on VCards or can they be any arbitrary size? What about a VCard containing a single contact?

Comment: Check out the 4.0 RFC: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6350. I didn't see anything in it, so the limits may be around the software consuming it. For example, there's no reason a text file can't contain GBs of data, but the average vCard parse/display mechanism would probably fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TimMedora said, the specs do not place any limits how large a single vCard can be.  Nor does it place any limits on how many vCards there can be in a single vCard file.

But vCards are typically very small in size.  The parser that you are using may not be programmed to handle such large amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to import a single vCard that was 6.5 MB containing about 70 contacts into my android galaxy s8.  It failed saying "imported" although only a couple had been.  Note the size/contact might seen rather large, but each had a base64 encoded photo.

To get them all to import I split it up into only about 5 such contacts per .vcf file.   Then they all loaded properly.